# Angularjs (1.3) - UI element values are cleared (unbound) when once hidden and shown back the div element of current controller from master

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

In Angularjs values are cleared only for UI components like (input, textarea, button) when I use ng-model to bind them. In the Master page (asp.net), we use two <div> elements, we dynamically hide one of them. The problem is when showing back the first element after hiding, the values in the components are cleared but the bound $scope object has values.

```
<input ng-disabled="true" type="text" datepopup ng-model="dataCopy.issueDate" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off" />
```

There is no unbound/unbind event in Angularjs 1.3 to diagnose when these values are cleared.

When I use <span> with ng-bind as shown below, it persists the values and doesn't clear.

```
<span ng-bind="dataCopy.issueDate"></span>
```

Any idea, when what can make these values cleared (unbound) from these controls, and why it doesn't happen on <span> elements?

Answer (score 0):

We designed the <div> elements with <form class="form-horizontal">, that's why it cleared all the values of the div element. When I replace <form> with <table> it works fine.

It puzzled me for a couple of days, I hope this helps others.